# CakePHP pagination and the get parameters

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a problem with the pagination in my search page.
When a user search something I have a url like `domain.com/search/?s=keyword`
but paginator gives me links like `domain.com/search/page:x`,
so in the next and prev and numbers page the get parameter is lost. I need to configure paginator to get links like `domain.com/search/page:x/?s=keyword`
But I can't do this.

I need to know how to configure

```
$paginator->options();
$paginator->next();
$paginator->prev();
$paginator->numbers();
```

to get the needed efect.
Thanx.

Answer (score 21):

create the options array

```
$options = array(
    'url'=> array(
        'controller' => 'posts', 
        'action' => 'search', 
        '?' => 'keyword='.$keyword
     )
);
```

set it to the helper

```
$paginator->options($options)
```

and then you can use the paginator helper while retaining the GET variables.

hope that it helped :)

to make it easier you can putl $paginator options in your view or .ctp file

```
$this->Paginator->options['url']['?'] = $this->params['ur];
```

then put the value that you want :)

Comment: +1 Also, if you don't want to overwrite the current pagination options (ie page number, etc.) you can append to the options array: `$this->Paginator->options['url']['?'] = $queryString;`

Answer (score 4):

To pass all URL arguments to paginator functions, add the following to your view:
Plain Text View

```
$paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
```

That's it.
See
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

Answer (score 2):

I used Matyas solution, but for $keyword I did like this:

```
$queryString = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$options = array('url'=> array('controller' => 'post', 'action' => 'search', '?' => $queryString[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

use statement in your view for pass parameters while pagination

```
$paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
```

this is simplest way to pass parameters.

Some time `$this->passedArgs` not working at that time pass static value at there and try with that static value.

```
$paginator->options(array('url' => array('a', 'b')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this comment](http://q2interactive.net/view/retain-get-parameters-in-the-url-when-using-cakephp-paginator.html#comment-69).

I used it, it works fine.

in app_controller file:

```
function _paginatorURL() {
  $passed = "";
  $retain = $this->params['url'];
  unset($retain['url']);
  $this->set('paginatorURL',array($passed, '?' => http_build_query($retain)));
}

function beforeFilter()
{
  $this->_paginatorURL();
}
```

in views file:

```
  <?php $paginator->options = array( 'url' => $paginatorURL );?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do it like this:

```
function list_results($keywords)
  {
  $data = $this->paginate('Posts', array('Post.title LIKE' => '%'.$keywords.'%'));
  }
```

Comment: Sorry Paweł, you don't understand me.
I have the $data in my view but only in page one, if I go to page 2 I go to domain.com/search/page:2 because $paginator in the view generate links like this, so the get "s" value is not present in my controller, if I go to domain.com/search/page:2/?s=keyword I've got the 2 page of the search result.

I don't know how to force $paginator to generate links like domain.com/search/page:x/?s=keyword

Comment: Oh, yeah, I get what you mean now. Well I would like to see the solution to this as well. One thing you can do is use the session component to carry the keyword through pages. It does have some disadvantages though (can't give a link to someone).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but found a simple solution that works for me. Add following in view file -

```
$paginator->options(array('url' => array_merge($this->passedArgs,
array('?' => ltrim(strstr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '&'), '&')))));
```

Found it [here](http://www.bradezone.com/2011/01/06/query-strings-and-the-cakephp-paginator/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Paginator->options['url']['?'] = ['key' => $this->params['url']['value']];
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and what it adds that the other answers do not already cover.