# Cakephp2 pagination with GET parameters

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a list page with a filter form and Im submitting the form using get method. How to pass the querystring parameters along with the pagination links. I have checked this link
[CakePHP pagination and the get parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325544/cakephp-pagination-and-the-get-parameters) but this->passedArgs is coming as empty. Im using cakephp2. Whats the best option to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some code I use in a CakePHP 1.3 project. I believe it should still work on CakePHP 2.0 as well (put this in the view where your filter form is):

```
// Make sure we pass any set filters to the Paginator helper
$urlParams = $this->params['url'];
unset($urlParams['url']);

$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => array('?' => http_build_query($urlParams))));
```

Comment: how to apply the same to paginator sort function ?

Comment: @binoy The sorting function should not be affected by this code, it just additionally adds any selected filters to the Paginator URL's.

Comment: thanks.. I have given the code in the bottom of the page so it did not work with sort function. I moved to top and its working..